# How to add the Babel preprocessor on a project scaffolded with gulp-angular some time ago?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, babeljs

Basically I'm working on a project that was created using Yeoman with generator-gulp-angular. At that time we didn't add Babel or any other preprocessor yet now I'm trying to do just this. Should this be done somehow manually or there's a more sane way?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing.

The best option would be to start a new scaffolding with the options that you now realize are the ones you want, and rebuild the app into this project, but nobody ever has enough time to do that. So that's probably not really a possibility for you.

Another option is to set up a new gulp-angular project, using the new options (babel etc.), and compare it side-by-side with your "legacy" project. Copy in any build-related files, and then see what's changed using version control. You'll notice everything in the main gulp folder has changed, the index.html, the .babelrc, .eslintrc, gulpfile.js, as well as the bower/npm dependencies, the syntax of core files (index.route.js etc.), and a few other things.

But even after updating these and understanding what is new in them, I am still a bit stuck and not seeing any useful error messages in my build or on my browser console. I'm commenting here, to let you know other people hear you and to receive any notification about any responses to this question. I don't know if any of this is being resolved in the replacement for yeoman, fountainJS.

Good luck! Don't give up! :)